# How to display multidimensional array with *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, typoscript

I newbe in js,ts,ionic

I got this array called 'stores' in my home.ts:

```
0: {name: "wwwe", floor: 1}
1: {name: "weeqe", floor: -3}
2: {name: "weewqe", floor: -2}
3: {name: "qweqweqwe", floor: -2}
```

And I need too show it through *ngFor. I have this in home.html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let store of stores">
<ion-card-header >
{{store.name}}
</ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

But this is show empty page!

Help pls

Also I tryed this:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let store of stores; let i=index">
<ion-card-header >
{{store[i].name}}
</ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

Dont work.

I read that I must to change the object to an array, but I do not understand how to do this in my case. I need all the array values in one place.

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    var stores: Store[] = []
    var json;
    this.http.get('http/link/to/json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            json = data.data;
            for (var i of json.stores){
                stores.push({ 'name': i.name, 'floor': i.floor[0]  });
            }

        });

    console.log(stores);

  }


}
```

This is show console.log(stores) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGsys.png

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. A multidimensional array is an array which contains arrays. Your array simply contains objects.

Comment: But how to do multidimensional array?

Comment: Don't this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36118657/4636715

Comment: Yours is an array of objects. 0,1,2 and so on are index numbers. and `{}` is an object at a specific index. your HTML should work as it is.

Comment: Show us your `home.ts`. The first two code samples should work as they are.

Comment: can you add code snippet then we can fix it easily

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you! I have no errors, clean console and white window. My loop just dont work.

Comment: I doubt you have your data missing in variables. I mean variables itself are empty. Can you inspect HTML and see if the variable did print content?

Comment: @KishorPawar in my HTML just this: `<!--bindings={}-->` instead of loop with <ion-card>

Comment: did your console.log print stores? can you create a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @KishorPawar yes console.log print stores, I added screenshot of output to the post

Comment: @KishorPawar sorry, i dont know how to create ionic code in jsfiddle

Comment: Try printing `stores` directly into html or static text next to `{{store.name}}`

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @KishorPawar Unfortunately, nothing is shown. Clear ion-card  starts showing up only when i remove `*ngFor` and `{{store.name}}`

Comment: @KishorPawar Angular 5.2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `stores` variable outside the constructor

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

// This way so you can reference it in the ngFor
stores: Store[] = [] 

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    var json;
    this.http.get('http/link/to/json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            json = data.data;
            for (var i of json.stores){
                this.stores.push({ 'name': i.name, 'floor': i.floor[0]  });
            }

        });

    console.log(this.stores);

  }


}
```